# Interface and enum typescript in react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a project and I have a strange problem.  i have an enum

```
export enum ButtonTypes {
    Primary = 'primary',
    Secondary = 'secondary',
    Ghost = 'ghost',
}
```

and I want to use these enum values inside an interface

```
export interface IButtonProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement> {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    type: keyof typeof ButtonTypes;
}
```

but I got this error :
***Parsing error: Unexpected token***

> 11 |     type: keyof typeof ButtonTypes;

the error is indicating that there is an unexpected token after the `keyof`

the component code

```
export default function Button(props: IButtonProps) {
    const { children, type } = props;
    return (
        <Styles.ButtonWrapper type={ButtonTypes[type]}>
            {children}
        </Styles.ButtonWrapper>
    );
}
```

to have an complete picture on the code i have added my styled component code

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { colors } from '../theme';
import { ButtonTypes } from './Button';

interface IButtonWrapperProps {
    type: ButtonTypes;
}
const BACKGROUND_MAP: any = {
    [ButtonTypes.Primary]: colors.primary,
};

const TEXT_COLOR_MAP: any = {
    [ButtonTypes.Primary]: colors.white,
};
const BORDER_COLOR_MAP: any = {
    [ButtonTypes.Primary]: colors.primary,
};

export const ButtonWrapper = styled.a<IButtonWrapperProps>`
    background-color: ${(props) => BACKGROUND_MAP[props.type]};
    color: ${(props) => TEXT_COLOR_MAP[props.type]}
    border: ${(props) => BORDER_COLOR_MAP[props.type]};
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
`;
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `type: ButtonTypes` ?

Comment: @Batajus i can't do these it will fire another error ,and that because i want to pass props to component type = {ButtonTypes[type]}

Comment: i have added an component code in my post

Comment: two questions: 
1) Why are you defining props extra? why dont you use "FC" to type the  component? ( export const Button: FC<AddTypeHere> = (props) => {...}
2) use keyof only? -> type: keyof Buttontypes

Comment: wired, works fine for me. TS 4.4

Comment: That's because you are accessing type in `<Styles.ButtonWrapper type={ButtonTypes[type]}>` which literally is an enum `ButtonTypes`. Instead you need to go one level deep i.e. `<Styles.ButtonWrapper type={ButtonTypes[type][Primary]}>`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, it is a problem in my package.json, all packages were very old I just have upgraded all packages and it worked fine.

**don't be a fool like me, always keep an eye for your packages**